# WXPython: Issue on Populating a Listbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I am trying to populate a list box from a list in python using this code:

```
import wx
class ListBoxFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'List Box Example',  size=(500, 500))
    panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

    btn1 = wx.Button(self, 1, 'List Items', (300, 130))
    btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ListItems)

    listBox1 = wx.ListBox(choices=[], name='listBox1', parent=self, pos=wx.Point(8,          48), size=wx.Size(184, 256), style=0)

def ListItems(self, event):
    sampleList = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five','six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven','twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen']
    for item in sampleList:
        self.listBox1.Insert(0,item)
```

But I am encountering with following error:
**AttributeError: 'ListBoxFrame' object has no attribute 'listBox1'**
Can you please let me know what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your `__init__`:

```
listBox1 = wx.ListBox(..etc..)
```

should be:

```
self.listBox1 = wx.ListBox(..etc..)
```

All instance access in Python work through `self.`.

Comment: Thanks Ned, it works now but I have two questions for you, please.1- why we do not need to put the self. for button like btn1 = wx.Button(self, 1, 'List Items', (300, 130)) and 2- I was getting another error when i was trying to Insert the items into list box as"return _controls_.ListBox_Insert(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: Required argument 'pos' (pos 3) not found" but after I change the insert method to Append method it worked fine, can you please let me know why? thanks again for your perfect comment and help